# Creating a mock in phpunit without mocking any methods?

Tags: mocking, phpunit

When I'm unit-testing my php code with PHPUnit, I'm trying to figure out the right way to mock an object without mocking any of its methods.

The problem is that if I don't call `getMockBuilder()->setMethods()`, then all methods on the object will be mocked and I can't call the method I want to test; but if I *do* call `setMethods()`, then I need to tell it what method to mock but I don't want to mock any methods at all. But I need to create the mock so I can avoid calling the constructor in my test.

Here's a trivial example of a method I'd want to test:

```
class Foobar
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // stuff happens here ...
    }

    public function myMethod($s)
    {
        // I want to test this
        return (strlen($s) > 3);
    }
}
```

I might test `myMethod()` with:

```
$obj = new Foobar();
$this->assertTrue($obj->myMethod('abcd'));
```

But this would call Foobar's constructor, which I don't want. So instead I'd try:

```
$obj = $this->getMockBuilder('Foobar')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
$this->assertTrue($obj->myMethod('abcd'));
```

But calling `getMockBuilder()` without using `setMethods()` will result in all of its methods being mocked and returning null, so my call to `myMethod()` will return null without touching the code I intend to test.

My workaround so far has been this:

```
$obj = $this->getMockBuilder('Foobar')->setMethods(array('none'))
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
$this->assertTrue($obj->myMethod('abcd'));
```

This will mock a method named 'none', which doesn't exist, but PHPUnit doesn't care. It will leave myMethod() unmocked so that I can call it, and it will also let me disable the constructor so that I don't call it. Perfect! Except that it seems like cheating to have to specify a method name that doesn't exist - 'none', or 'blargh', or 'xyzzy'.

What would be the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can pass `null` to `setMethods()` to avoid mocking any methods. Passing an empty array will mock all methods. The latter is the default value for the methods as you've found.

That being said, I would say the need to do this might point out a flaw in the design of this class. Should this method be made static or moved to another class? If the method doesn't require a completely-constructed instance, it's a sign to me that it might be a utility method that could be made static.

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks like setMethods(null) is what I want; this causes no methods to be mocked. setMethods(array()), on the other hand, appears to cause all methods to be mocked, same as not using setMethods() at all. I couldn't find this documented anywhere. What do you mean by "empty parents" though?

Comment: Also - I am puzzled by your comment. Aside the specifics of the trivial myMethod() example I provided above, why would a method that needs to be tested this way make you feel that the method should be moved to another class or made static?

Comment: @BrianKendig - Autocorrect fail on "parents" which should be "parens". :) I just checked the source and there's no default so you must pass in `null` yourself.

Comment: Thank you; your help is much appreciated. I opened https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/509 to ask that this functionality be mentioned in the PHPUnit documentation.

Comment: And I see you edited your comment - I agree that a method that doesn't require its instance to be constructed might be better off as static; but even if it does require its constructor, I still prefer my unit tests to disable the constructor and set up the object themselves. If a unit tests the constructor *and* the method at the same time, then it's not really a unit test, in my opinion. :-)

Comment: I must be the only person on the planet who manually creates mocked objects ;-/ What ever happened to `class TestableFoobar extends Foobar`?

Comment: @BrianKendig - I used to focus more on unit testing at the method level but have since joined the class-is-the-unit camp. Using TDD has helped as the tests become a great example on how to use the class. If you use a bunch of mocks to skip the constructor--something you'll never do in production code--you lose this. And since your test code has no tests, you want it to be as straight-forward as possible.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith - I do this if I need a stub with a simple canned response or that ignores method calls that would normally do something. I use mocks when I want to a) validate the calls being made and b) give specific return values in response.

Answer (score 3):

Another hacky, but succinct solution is simply to list the magic constructor as one of the mocked methods:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('MyClass', array('__construct'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case, any method, e.g. that is called through the entityManager, can be used you might be able to use this:

```
$this->entityManager
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method($this->anything())
        ->willReturn($repository);
```

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of PHPUnit, since the `setMethods` function is deprecated, you can replace `setMethods(array('none'))` / `setMethods(null)` with `onlyMethods([])`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use `getMock()` directly.

`$mock = $this->getMock('MyClass', null, array(), null, false);`

Comment: getMock() is deprecated

Answer (score -9):

This worked for me:

```
$this->getMock($class, array(), array(), '', false);
```