# Replacing service in Symfony2 for testing dynamically

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, phpunit

Environment: Symfony2, Guzzle

Problem: I want to write functional tests and replace the guzzle client used in the tested class with a mock client class *sometimes*.

In detail:

- class BookFetcher uses class ApiConnector which uses Guzzle to
  retrieve the data from somewhere else
- I want to write some tests which actually use the original ApiConnector to make sure that nothing has been changed at the other side
- as this is slow I want to mock the ApiConnector in all other tests using a mock class
- At the moment I replace the ApiConnector class with a MockClass in config_test.yml (parameters section). This affects ALL tests (no more contract testing).
- I need a way to replace the ApiConnector class with my mock class sometimes

Comment: I always create a service  that collaborate with Guzzle. In functional environment, ... I just mock collaborator. In this case, Guzzle.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of `ApiConnector` using `new` keyword, inject mock `Guzzle` and use it for testing.

Another option you have is you can mock `ApiConnector` while mocking only some of it methods (maybe the ones doing the actual connections?) [using `phpUnit`'s setMethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398284/creating-a-mock-in-phpunit-without-mocking-any-methods).